# How to get referrer URL when visitors coming from HTTPS websites as Google

Tags: redirect, nginx, https

When visitors are coming from HTTPS Websites i can't get URL referrer, i want to do this to prevent users whose redirected from a specific HTTPS Websites, so im asking you if is there any possibility to do this from NGINX website configuration.

Prevention is successfully done when users come from HTTP web sites.
this is my NGINX configuration :

```
server {

listen 80;
server_name .....
.....

location / {
if ($http_referer ~* (www.website.com) ) {
 return 500;
 }
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing about nginx. Fast "google" can show you, that browser do not send Referer for links from https to http. There is two possible ways to solve it. 1) Meta tag on **origin** site. 2) Move your site to https - referer work well for links from https to https and from http to https.